# What is the paper that the FlinkCep implementation based on?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

I need to know the if there is/are paper(s) behind the implementation of FlinkCEP. If there, then what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the overall approach is based on [a paper from SIGMOD '08 by Agrawal, etal](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~yanlei/publications/sase-sigmod08.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @David Anderson